# Different way of writing "attackable" and "repairable"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, adverbs

In programming, we say an object is *capable* of doing something.  For example, an object may be *drivable* or *repairable*.  This lets us know what actions the different parts of a computer program are able to perform or receive.

The English words we use don't have to actually exist, for example we can use *dieable* which could imply that the object can die.  This is not a great example, but it should get the point across.

I'm looking for a way to express the capability for an object to *attack* something.  If I say it's *attackable* then it implies it can be attacked, not that it's capable of attacking.

I also cannot use *it attacks* or *it can attack* as it should use the single word format with *-able* on the end if at all possible.  It also cannot use hyphens and must be one word.

I am also looking for suggestions for *repairable* but implying that it performs repairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices to indicate that something is capable of attacking. "Offensive", "offending", "aggressive", "aggressor", "harmful", and "combat[ive]" are possible choices.

As for indicating that something can perform repairs, you have options like "medic[al]", "service[r]", "maintainer", "aider", "mender".

I don't think there are "able" words that indicate an ability to do things to others the way you seem to want. Something is "X-able" if X can be done to it.

Comment: Agree with 'able' not really working.  It's how it was done in Java, but I think I need to change things up a bit for what I'm working on now.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider [weaponised](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weaponized) (or [weaponisable](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=%22weaponizable%22&pbx=1&oq=%22weaponizable%22&aq=f&aqi=g-v2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4781l5218l5l5531l2l2l0l0l0l0l188l297l0.2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=acc135da6d1347b&biw=1238&bih=857)) if you don't like [attack-capable](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=%22attack-capable%22+-%22capable+of%22&pbx=1&oq=%22attack-capable%22+-%22capable+of%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=12344l19141l4l20156l14l14l0l0l0l0l547l2655l2.10.1.5-1l14l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=acc135da6d1347b&biw=1238&bih=857).

Answer (score 0):

For the "it can attack"-able case, try *weaponable* and *armable*.  For "it can repair"-able, perhaps *medicable*, from *medic*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but David had "aggressor" which I think fits better.  However, armable is still in the running.