# What's the word for something that can attack?

Tags: single-word-requests

Something that is `attackable` can be attacked, taking its passive meaning. However, I'm looking for its active meaning, i.e. `something that can attack`. Is there a word for this in the English Language? Is it just `attackable` too?

For example, this would be used in sentences like: "All the attacking units are [something that can attack]s".

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you need a new word and what you are trying to mean by it?

Comment: @Rathony I'm not asking for a new word, there is so many words in the English language I wouldn't be surprised if this was a word already and I just didn't know of it.

Comment: [Power Thesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/invasive) lists about  90 synonyms of **invasive** including 'hostile' and 'attacking'. Your sentence might be finished 'operational', 'active', 'ready for action'....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a single word, but I'd say ***potential attackers***. Here's an example in the wild from [The New York Post](http://nypost.com/2015/11/16/french-police-place-over-100-people-under-house-arrest/):

> France carries out raids, names more potential attackers
>
> PARIS — French police raided 168 locations across the country and detained nearly two dozen people as authorities identified more members of a sleeper cell said to be behind the Paris attacks that killed 129 people.

Your example, albeit tautological, would go along the lines of:

*"All the attacking units are potential attackers"*

In this related post ([Different way of writing “attackable” and “repairable”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53199/different-way-of-writing-attackable-and-repairable)) there are some words that could fit the bill, such as *potential aggresor* or *weaponisable*, but they aren't etymologically related to "attack", if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I think this does fit what I'm looking for, thanks :)

Comment: Hummmmm, "something that can attack".  Anything can.  A predator is most likely to. "potential", good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the hyphenated adjective “[combat-ready](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/combat-ready),” which ‘Dictionary[dot]com’ defines as “sufficiently equipped, trained, and numerically strong to engage an enemy,”  you could perhaps consider   “[attack-ready](https://books.google.com/books?id=hCiU3LPC5rgC&pg=PA237&dq=%22are+attack-ready%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX37zTl4nLAhUN1WMKHdKLBs0Q6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22are%20attack-ready%22&f=false)."
(example usage from ‘STARS FALL ON PUDAHUEL 2nd Edition: (Never say: never, always or forever)’ by Mario Terrazas Guzmán, via Google Books)

If being “attack-ready” is too “on the verge/brink of attacking” for your context, you could scale it back a bit to “[attack-capable](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ewc2AAAAIAAJ&q=%22are+attack-capable%22&dq=%22are+attack-capable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT0YzMn4nLAhVQxGMKHey5CxYQ6AEIIjAB).”
(example of usage from ‘Hearings, Reports and Prints of the House Committee on Armed Services,’ via Google Books)